# How to relate data correctly?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, entity-relationship

I have this database where I am storing clothes from different retailers:

- So each product has different colors
- Each product also has different sizes
- Each size has also different colors
- Now for each product and for each different size and color, there could be different prices.

I am using Django for this, and I am asking any thoughts on how this database relation might work out.

Would I have something like this?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()

class Size(models.Model):
    size_of_product = model.CharField()
    product = model.ForeignKey(Product)

class Color(models.Model):
    color_of_product = model.CharField()
    product = model.ForeignKey(Product)
    size = model.ManyToManyField(Size,though="Price")

class price(model.Model):
    size = model.ForeignKey(Size)
    color = model.ForeignKey(Color)
    date =model.Date()
```

Could anyone please  suggest me of a better solution because obviously I don't have much practice with databases yet?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following to be close with your initial design:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Size(models.Model):
    size_of_product = models.CharField()

class Color(models.Model):
    color_of_product = models.CharField()

class ProductPrice(model.Model):
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
    product = modelss.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField(...)
```

With that you'll have a list of products, a list of sizes and a list of colors. Whenever you want to add a variation for a product, you'll just a new `ProductPrice`  instance with the price of the combination of all three (product, size, color) instances.

However, as a general comment, most e-shops do not work like this since products have more characteristics than color or size (for example manufacturer or material).

So, a more general solution would be to have a `Category` model that defines different categories of things (f.e shoes, jackets, trousers). Each `Category` has a number of `Characteristic`s (for example color or material) and each `Characteristic` has a number of possible `Value`s (for example blue, brown or leather, cotton etc). Finally, your `Product` which will be a specific item with a price, will belong to a specific `Category` and have specific `Value`s for each of the `Characteristic`s of that `Category`.

```
class Characteristic(models.Model):
    name = modes.CharField()


class Category(models.Model):
    name = modes.CharField()
    # Each Category can have many characteristics and each
    # characteristic may be related to many categories (e.g
    # both shoes and jackets have color
    characteristics = models.ManyToManyField(Characteristic)


class Value(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()
    # each value belongs to a specific characteristic
    characteristic = models.ForeignKey(Characteristic)


class Product(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
     # A product will have a number of values (e.g brown, leather)
     values = models.ManyToManyField(Value)
     prices = models.DecimalField()
```

So using the above design we can support as many characteristics as we want for each of our Products.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice! Only thing is that I can have a combination of size and color with different prices, and I don't know if I can achieve that here. So like a color:blue size:Medium will have one price, and color:red with size:medium can have another size.

Comment: You can definitely achieve this with *both* approaches. I think it is obvious that with the first approach, you'll just add a ``ProductPrice`` for product X with values (X, blue, medium, price1) and (X, red, medium, price2). Concerning the 2nd approach, you'll just add two ``Product``s with different prices and *different* values (one with red and medium and another with blue and medium)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're modeling clothing. (Pun absolutely intended!) Fine, let's see what we can do about that.

- Each product has different colors

Fine. The entity `product` has an attribute `color`. Let's continue.

- Each product also has different sizes

Fine again. The entity `product` has an attribute `size`. So far so good.

- Each size has also different colors

Um. Hold on. While a product may have a size and a color, a size cannot have a color nor a color have a size. As attributes, these relate to `product`, not to each other. Your modeling breaks down at this point.

I think what you mean is that all colors are not available in all sizes. This is different. In this case, a color is not directly related to a product, but a product/size combination.

You have correctly identified this as a many-to-many relationship. But it is between color and an intermediate product/size combination, not directly to product.